# What do you call an asset (e.g. of a hotel) that can't be controlled or owned?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, for a hotel room:

Assets:

- Beautiful italian marble floors
- 2 beds
- A 5-star rated customer service
- Situated in the center of Londen

_____:

- Amazing view
- Usually 30 degrees celcius between May and June
- Fish market within 5km open on most Wednesdays
- Friendly local community
- Easy to get a taxi

From the standpoint of a hotel manager, the first few examples would all be in his or her control. But the second list would not (e.g. someone could block the amazing view, or there could be a taxi-strike). The best I could come up with is something like "public resources" or "unreliable assets". Would there be a better word?

Comment: *Features*, *Advantageous features* ??

Comment: Hotel rooms are often advertised as *featuring* amazing views, lending support to @TrevorD's suggestion. Although I wouldn't consider being 5km from a fish market that's open on *some* Wednesdays a feature... nor worthy of advertisement.

Comment: I think *features* comes pretty close, thank you. I'm also considering *resources*, although for example a great view isn't exactly a resource.

Comment: One could also refer to them as 'bonuses.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points you've mentioned can fall under one or more of the following:

**Setting** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/setting)

> 1. The place or type of surroundings where something is positioned or where an event takes place
>
> *"a romantic house in a wonderful setting beside the River Wye"*
> *"With a wonderful setting situated at the front of the glass dome, it affords unbroken views of the River Irvine, the church spires of the town and the hills beyond."*
> *"All of the museums offer stylish settings for events and can cater for up to 1500 guests."*
> *"Downpatrick Library is an appropriate setting for the event"*

**Atmosphere** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/atmosphere)

> 2. The pervading tone or mood of a place, situation, or creative work
>
> *"the hotel has won commendations for its friendly, welcoming atmosphere"*
> *"Soothing music playing in the background created a relaxing atmosphere, setting the tone for the evening."*
> *"Such festivals attract large groups of young people together in an atmosphere of welcome, adventure and celebration."*

**Amenity** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/amenity)

> 1. A desirable or useful feature or facility of a building or place
>
> *"the property is situated in a convenient location, close to all local amenities"*
> *"You get better services, better local amenities, even public transport is better."*
>
> 1.1 *(mass noun)* The pleasantness or attractiveness of a place
>
> *"It would not take a fortune to create a clean and tidy looking river bank and with a little imagination a very good amenity could be created in this area."*
> *"National policy could give a more balanced steer to the conflicts of social justice and affordable housing against landscape and amenity."*
> *"A lot of the surrounding countryside has been classified as National Park, and is great amenity to have on the doorstep."*